# Astra Pro RGB & Depth publishing rate not quite same. [Closed]

Tags: ros, depth-image, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I want to use Orbbec Astra Pro in ROS Indigo inside Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed the ROS compatible OPenNI2 and now able to run the launch code. The Astra Pro Camera starts perfectly without any issue.

Now the problem is when i check the publishing rate of RGB and Depth stream I see that they are not quite same.

Here are the outputs..

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

What can I do to get 30hz publish rate for both RGB and Depth

Cheers,

Prasanna

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285203/astra-pro-rgb-&-depth-publishing-rate-not-quite-same.-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
Please check our [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do_Not), specifically the *Do Not* section, which states:

> **DO NOT** post a screenshot of the terminal or source file.

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2018-03-13**:
OK Sir, it was a mistake. It won't be repeated. But I'm closing this issue as I have found the bug.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
Just keep it in mind for your next question.

> But I'm closing this issue as I have found the bug.

It would be nice if you could post what you found as an answer and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the silly question. I solved the issue.

Here is a solution to my problem regarding the publish rate of RGB image.

previously it was . and thats way I was getting 15Hz rate, but now it's 30Hz as I have changed it.

before ---------  param name="frame_rate" value="15"

after ---------  param name="frame_rate" value="30"

This is for the libuvc_ros driver that I'm using for Astra Pro with astra_pro.launch file.

using the following command

```
$ roslaunch astra_launch astra_pro.launch

<node pkg="libuvc_camera" type="camera_node" name="astra_pro_uvc">
    <!-- Parameters used to find the camera -->
    <param name="vendor" value="0x2bc5"/>
    <param name="product" value="0x0501"/>
    <param name="serial" value=""/>
    <!-- If the above parameters aren't unique, choose the first match: -->
    <param name="index" value="0"/>

    <!-- Image size and type -->
    <param name="width" value="640"/>
    <param name="height" value="480"/>
    <!-- choose whichever uncompressed format the camera supports: -->
    <param name="video_mode" value="uncompressed"/> <!-- or yuyv/nv12/jpeg -->
    <param name="frame_rate" value="30"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="$(arg camera)_rgb_optical_frame"/>

    <param name="timestamp_method" value="start"/> <!-- start of frame -->
    
    
    <!-- Change has to be done here to add the camera calibration file-->
    
    <!-- <param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///tmp/cam.yaml"/> -->




    <param name="auto_exposure" value="3"/> <!-- use aperture_priority auto exposure -->
    <param name="auto_white_balance" value="false"/>
  </node>

</group> <!-- rgb -->
```

Thanks,

Prasanna

---

Originally posted by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) with karma: 92 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:\

> previously it was .

it was what?